# Getting access to Raspberry PI registers in C programming

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, cpu-registers

I am trying to get access to the register of my Raspberry Pi.

To be a bit more specific, http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf has some Hardware Timers on page 172-173.

I want to use them because I have to write two functions `HW_GetTimer()` and `HW_ClearTimer()`.

I can't find a good way to communicate with those registers. Is this possible? Is there an existing C function that I don't know about?

Comment: Is that something you can do in user space? If you're lucky there's already a kernel interface to do this for you, else you might have to write a kernel module to do this and call to that from your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a word of warning: These registers are likely used by the Operating System, so if you fiddle with them, chances are that you break something...

That said, there are two options:

- The proper one: write a kernel driver and you'll have plenty of functions to access the hardware in a sane and controlled way. Or chances are that there is already a driver that does exactly what you are trying to do, if that's the case, you just find it and use the interface it exposes. Reading the kernel source is fun!
- The easy one: from user-mode land, open `/dev/mem` and `mmap()` the addresses you want to access into your process memory. Then you can read/write (use `volatile` pointers, please!) as you will. Note that you cannot `read()`/`write()` from/to `/dev/mem`, only `mmap()`.

Obviously, for the user-mode thing you have to have the proper permissions or be root.

Comment: but nmap() does not really change in the registers, it only maps what it in there. So i cant reset the hardware timer... maybe a multimediatimer is a solution ?

Comment: `mmap()` will map whatever is in there and returns a pointer. You then use the (cast to volatile) pointer to modify the memory-mapped registers.

Answer (score 0):

Guess: You are using linux.

If you are trying to do this in conjunction with Linux, there usually is a driver for (yes even for timers!) which are used internally for scheduling, tasklets and other stuff - in userspace you should use `poll` or `epoll` without any filedescriptors and just use the timeout. This will get you as close as it can get to schedulers granularity.

Another way would be to check the kernel code *if* the timer is used, if not you could simply export it via a kernel module, though that requires at least a basic understanding of the CPU, how the kernel works and how it is implemented without security implications or risk of crash (if not both).

---

I omit the bare metal way here...